# Azure WebJob Service bus nugget OnMessageAsync equivalent on version 3 for net core

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

I have a net core 2.2 project which need to use Microsoft.AzureWebJobs.ServiceBus package to handle queues.
but on version 3 the method `OnMessageAsync` I was using disappeared. I changed version for compatibility.

I had a piece of code like this:

```
queueClient.OnMessageAsync(message=> Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(()=> ProcessMessage(message))));
```

what's the equivalent method now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is still there, just got renamed. It's now called `RegisterMessageHandler` and is still available via `QueueClient`. The article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) demonstrates how to use the API.